# guake is showing ->"bash: /usr/libexec/vte-urlencode-cwd: No such file or directory"

Tags: guake

i was tring to compile a c++ code in guake terminal .it showed "bash: /usr/libexec/vte-urlencode-cwd: No such file or directory"

Comment: did you you VTE tools like Tilix terminal before? maybe this issue is something similar https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606862/why-i-can-not-get-terminator-to-use-the-default-defined-shell

Comment: I exited Guake and returned to it now I get bash: /usr/libexec/vte-urlencode-cwd: No such file or directory